# Vibrate ipod touch 4

Tags: ipod-touch

I buy Ipod Touch 4.
But, when someone is call me to my facetime account, it doesnt vibrate like say the apple description ipod article.

How can i activate it.

Comment: This isn't a programming-related question, which is what this site is for, so I have downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

iPod doesn't have vibro. Physically. No way.